# How to move reusable JavaScript code in separate file, than the main and use it several times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages, code-reuse

I have a DataTable with a lot of properties. Every time I want to use it, I have to copy all of them. It makes my view's code behind a huge mess. So I decide  to create a separate .js file and copy the reusable code there but I can not reference it in my main file. Some part of my .js code is like bellow:

```
      function loadDataTable() {

        $(".yadcf-filter-range-date").persianDatepicker();
        dataTable = $('#SP1').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            pageLength: 10,
            infoFiltered: true,
            orderMulti: false,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            bStateSave: true,
            columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, targets: [15] }],
             .
             .
             .
       }
```

I create a function in another js file for example like bellow:

```
    function CommonPart(i) { 
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            pageLength: 10,
            infoFiltered: true,
            orderMulti: false,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            bStateSave: true,
            columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, targets: [i] }]
           }
```

I do not know how to use CommonPart in my main code for example like bellow:

```
      function loadDataTable() {

        $(".yadcf-filter-range-date").persianDatepicker();
        dataTable = $('#SP1').DataTable({
        CommonPart(15);
        ...
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to accomplish this is with [ECMAscript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

You can place each of those functions into a separate file. You can name the files what every you like, but I usually name them after the function it contains. For web, I'd give the file a `.js` file extension. In node, I'd give it a `.mjs` extension.

In each file, prepend [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) on each function like this:

```
export function funcName()
{
}
```

Then from your main code file, you can [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) your functions from those separate files like this:

```
import { funcName } from "./fileName.mjs";
```

After this, you can use the functions as if they were declared in your main code file (because they are now imported).

Answer (score 0):

The best and most trusted resource id MDN webdocs
link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

if you are still confused feel free to ask question..